# Get text of an element when it has more elements with text

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

I am using Selenium in Python and Firefox and I would want to get the text "TextB" in the next portion of HTML, I have tried with `element.get_attribute('textContent')` but it takes "TextA" too, is there any form of getting ONLY that text?

```
<p class="class_name" id="id_name">
    <i class="class_name2"></i>
    <b>TextA</b>
    TextB
</p>
```

Comment: Would you still like to consider (accept) a more _Pythonic_ Answer? I can construct one...

Comment: Yeah of course, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to get text content of the last child only

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('id_name')
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent', element)
```

Comment: That works but is not any other form that doesn't imply executing javascript? Although, in terms of efficiency, does executing javascript affect in a python code? i mean if you can choose between one option that uses javascript and another that doesn't, is there one option better than the another one?

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez there is no other option to directly extract the value of text node since Selenium doesn't support XPath syntax `//p/text()` (which should do what you want). Also you can try to get complete paragraph string value and then split it, but it doesn't seem to be much efficient. Another way is to remove child nodes `i` and `b`, but it also requires JavaScript execution (or get innerHTML and remove nodes using third-party library). So IMHO this is the best way to extract text in your exact case

Answer (score 0):

**Below gives you TextA which is the text of b tag**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='class_name']/b").text;
```

**Below gives you TextB which is the text of p tag**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='class_name']").text;
```

Comment: It gives me an error: `'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

Comment: can you post your code and the html content? also what your exact expectation is please?

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have provided to extract the text **TextB** in a more *Pythonic* way would be to use the [`splitlines()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_splitlines.asp) method as follows:

```
myText = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='class_name' and @id='id_name']").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[3]
```